# Eclipse Plugin Development: Display View under same folder

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I have a plug-in with two views.  Currently if I want to add the views I go to Window -> Show View -> Other.

The problem is, the two view show under separate folders (ImageView and MemoryView).  How do I get them to display under the same folder?

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?eclipse version="3.4"?>
<plugin>

   <extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.views">
      <category
            name="ImageView"
            id="ImageView">
      </category>
      <view
            name="ImageView"
            icon="icons/sample.gif"
            category="ImageView"
            class="imageplugin.views.ImageView"
            id="imageplugin.views.ImageView">
      </view>
   </extension>
     <extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.views">
      <category
            name="MemoryView"
            id="MemoryView">
      </category>
      <view
            name="MemoryView"
            icon="icons/sample.gif"
            category="MemoryView"
            class="imageplugin.views.MemoryView"
            id="imageplugin.views.MemoryView">
      </view>
   </extension>
   <extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.perspectiveExtensions">
      <perspectiveExtension
            targetID="org.eclipse.jdt.ui.JavaPerspective">
         <view
               ratio="0.5"
               relative="org.eclipse.ui.views.ProblemView"
               relationship="right"
               id="imageplugin.views.ImageView">
         </view>
         <view
               ratio="0.5"
               relative="org.eclipse.ui.views.ProblemView"
               relationship="right"
               id="imageplugin.views.MemoryView">
         </view>
      </perspectiveExtension>
   </extension>
   <extension
         point="org.eclipse.help.contexts">
      <contexts
            file="contexts.xml">
      </contexts>
   </extension>

</plugin>
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'same folder'? Are you talking about the display in 'Show View' or where they open on the workbench page?

Comment: @greg-449  The display in the "Show View"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your view `org.eclipse.ui.views` definitions have asked for the views to be in different categories by defining two different `category` entries. Just use a single category for both views to show them together, you do not have a define a separate category for each view:

```xml
<extension
     point="org.eclipse.ui.views">
  <category
        name="My Category"
        id="my.view.category">
  </category>
  <view
        name="ImageView"
        icon="icons/sample.gif"
        category="my.view.category"
        class="imageplugin.views.ImageView"
        id="imageplugin.views.ImageView">
  </view>
  <view
        name="MemoryView"
        icon="icons/sample.gif"
        category="my.view.category"
        class="imageplugin.views.MemoryView"
        id="imageplugin.views.MemoryView">
  </view>
</extension>
```